# Google Sheets Script - This script to copy columns works, but is it bad form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script works (and I'm quite proud of myself for having created my first script!), but I worry it could be bad form to have two copy/paste type functions especially considering they share a common set of columns. There will be a lot of data at one point (3,000 rows, 38 cols). Should there be a pause in between? Does the script finish the first function before starting the 2nd? Am I allowed to have two functions?  Thanks for the help.

```
//Copy 3 cols with original data into a backup range.
//Copy the 3 update cols to the original cols as values only

function testReplace_Orig_Review_tag_Rating_Cols_with_Updates () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var backup = sheet.getRange(3, 35, ss.getLastRow()-3, 3); // backup of original reviews, tags, ratings before they get overwritten 
  var update = sheet.getRange(3, 32, ss.getLastRow(), 3);  //updated reviews, tags, ratings
  var original = sheet.getRange(3, 13, ss.getLastRow()-3, 3); //original reviews, tags, ratings

original.copyTo(backup,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
update.copyTo(original,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);    
}
```

Background: I do an importxml on one sheet, and I copy/paste as values on another. 
In this values only page I have to update 3 cols. I added 3 cols at the end of my sheet where I do an importxml if the original cols are empty. But of course once those cols get updated I have to paste the data into the original cols as values only. Before I mess about with all of this I want to backukp those 3 original cols before they get overwritten. That's what my script does. It backups up the original cols, then pastes the updated cols into the original ones.

Comment: After a write, if a read is performed, apps script is smart enough to flush all previous changes.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function testReplace_Orig_Review_tag_Rating_Cols_with_Updates () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var backup = sheet.getRange(3,35,sheet.getLastRow()-2,3);
  var update = sheet.getRange(3,32,sheet.getLastRow()-2,3);  
  var original = sheet.getRange(3,13,sheet.getLastRow()-2,3);
  original.copyTo(backup,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  update.copyTo(original,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);    
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly flush has no effect on what the script does; it just shows the results live rather than waiting until the script is complete. Yes?  (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Comment: I noticed that you changed my getLastRow numbers. May I ask why?

Comment: I just noticed an error in there so I changed the ss to sheet in the getRange methods.  But any way in order to answer your question your rows start at 3 and end at sheet.getLastRow() so that means that there sheet.getLastRow()-3+1 rows in the range or just sheet.getLastRow()-2 rows.